# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime even if I provide valid Date format

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to convert string to a `DateTime` format, and my `string` looks in this format:

```
10.11.2017. 0:00:00
```

And I wanted to convert it to datetime like this:

```
DateTime expireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(MyFormat, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null);
```

I used HH because I'm using 24h format

But it thrown an error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
```

I'm wondering what is problem with this? I provided format 10.11.2017. which I thought will be acceptable by DateTime, but unfortunatelly it is not :/

Comment: In ParseExact the format string should match _exactly_ the input provided

Comment: Have you tried changing the format from `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"` to `"dd.MM.yyyy. H:mm:ss"`?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Yes, and that  was correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string s = "10.11.2017. 0:00:00";
DateTime expireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd.MM.yyyy. H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: one more thing mate, on some computers Date is written as 10/11/2017 and on some it's written as 10.11.2017 [ sometimes slash sometimes dot as a separator ] so how can i write exact parse there? What  is most practic  thing to do there? To convert DateTime ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"); independing of a separator time, and after that I might use ParseExact with dots without problems ? : )

Comment: Yes, convert the string to the common format before you use ParseExact.

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting it using the correct format. This should work:

```
DateTime expireDate = DateTime.ParseExact("10.11.2017. 0:00:00", "dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: *from the format. DateTime does not have any format.

Comment: I updated the answer to ensure what is inside the parameter

Comment: @Fildor is referring to the first line of your answer where you said "converting it TO the format".

Comment: You can convert a formatted string to a `DateTime`, not to a format, `DateTime` doesn't have a format.

Comment: Sorry all. My bad. My english failed. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not providing an exact date format. You are telling the ParseExact to expect a two digit hour but the example provides only a single 0. The same for the date part, you are expecting a / as separator, but you provide a string with a point.

It seems that your inputs are uncertain. Given this uncertainity I suggest to use DateTime.TryParseExact instead of ParseExact. This allows you to use an array of possible input formats to adjust the parsing to the exact format received

```
DateTime expireDate;
string test = "10.11.2017. 0:00:00";
string[] formats = {"dd.MM.yyyy. h:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy. h:mm:ss", 
                    "dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy. HH:mm:ss"};
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(test, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out expireDate);
if (result) 
    Console.WriteLine(expireDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

Not sure if the point after the year is a typo or not. In case of a typo then remove it also from the *formats* above

Comment: Why do you need multiple formats for single/double digit hours? The `h` specifier will cover both variants.